# Apply blend-tool on grid of squares with blending of size and color

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to create a grid made out of squares. Similar to the one in the image (without the wave effect).

My approach was to use the blend tool in multiple directions, but I cannot apply it to build a whole square out of these smaller squares.

Any idea on how to achieve this? Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

[image: Example Image]

Comment: Draw a rectangle then choose `Object > Path > Split into grid`

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right path (hah!) with using blends but you need to expand the blend (i.e. turn each square into it's own separate shape) before moving on to the next "blend".

So here is the process I would follow:

1. Create your two squares that you will create a blend with
2. Create your blend and change the blend options as desired
3. Expand the blend.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until you have your "grid" of blends.

Veerle Pieters, a talented Belgian illustrator and designer explains a similar process here: http://veerle-v2.duoh.com/blog/comments/illustrator_swatches_gradient_background_effect/

**Update:** You actually don't need to expand the blend. You can actually duplicate the original blend and change the colors and sizes of the source shapes used in the blend.